# How do I call this constuctor in java?

Tags: java, kotlin, constructor, callback, functional-interface

I have a library (.aar) file which i imported in java. The class is LSPatch which has a constructor.

```
public final class LSPatch public constructor(options: org.json.JSONObject, onDiscovery: (org.json.JSONObject) -> kotlin.Unit, onData: (org.json.JSONObject) -> kotlin.Unit, onStatus: (org.json.JSONObject) -> kotlin.Unit) {....}
```

Now I have no idea how to call this constuctor in java source code when I need to create an object of Class 'LSPatch'.
Like i want to create

```
LSPatch lspatch=new LSPatch(...);
```

When i try to do so it shows:
[image]
Am not able to relate it to java. Can anybody please help me. Just give me an idea what are those parameters and how to call the constructor practically.

Comment: Function interfaces are compatible with Java lambda

Comment: can u share a snippet where you are creating an object with this constuctor in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambdas in Java for 2nd, 3rd and 4th parameters:

```
LSPatch lspatch = new LSPatch(
            new JSONObject(),
            jsonObject -> {
                // do your stuff
                return null;
            },
            jsonObject -> {
                // do your stuff
                return null;
            },
            jsonObject -> {
                // do your stuff
                return null;
            }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance by passing a java lambda that does SAM conversion to kotlin's `Function` interface.

```java
LSPatch lspatch = new LSPatch(
    new JsonObject(),  // options
    jsonObject -> {  // onDiscovery
        // lambda body, your callback
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    },
    jsonObject -> {  // onData
        // lambda body, your callback
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    },
    jsonObject -> {  // onStatus
        // lambda body, your callback
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }
);
```

Comment: says Cant resolve this sysmbol "Unit". How do i import type Unit in java? its a kotlin data type for void right?

Comment: @SayanSen `import kotlin.Unit;`

Comment: it says the same thing for 'kotlin'. symbol cound not be resolved error. do i have to import or include something else before doing this?

Comment: @SayanSen weird, seems like library does not comes with its dependencies, you have to include yourself probably. In build.gradle `plugins {
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.3.72"
}
dependencies {
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
}`

Comment: i pasted the plugin block in my app level build.gradle file, but it says "Could not compile build file, startup failed: build file only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed "

Comment: where shall i keep this plugin block in my gradle file? i tried apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
but it throws "> Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' not found."

Comment: @SayanSen? add it inside your plugin block (already declared), instead of copy pasting.

Comment: i followed this link: https://segunfamisa.com/posts/setting-up-android-studio-for-kotlin-development#:~:text=Install%20Kotlin%20Plugin%20for%20Android%20Studio&text=To%20do%20this%2C%20navigate%20to,to%20apply%20the%20new%20plugin.